# Проблемы с выводом данных

Tags: c, вывод, ввод

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char gender[6];
    float height,weight;

    printf("Enter your gender:\n");
    scanf("%s",gender,"\n");
    printf("Enter your height:\n");
    scanf("%f",&height);
    printf("Enter your weight:\n");
    scanf("%f",&weight);

    printf("%s",gender);
    printf("%f",height);
    printf("%f",weight);

    return 0;
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему получается такой результат?

Пол и рост считываются и выводятся нормально, а с весом вот так:

```
Enter your gender:
men
Enter your height:
174.5
Enter your weight:
66.5
men174.50000066.500000
--------------------------------
Process exited after 11.55 seconds with return value 0
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо просто явно указать точность, с которой Вы хотите получить результат. Для этого между знаком `%` и `f` вставьте выражение типа `x.y`, обозначающее требуемое кол-во знаков. В приведенном примере `x = 10` — общее количество знакомест под значение переменной; `y = 3` — количество позиций после десятичной точки. В указанном примере (`weight = 66.5`) количество знакомест в выводимом числе меньше 10, поэтому свободные знакоместа слева от числа заполняются пробелами, а справа число дополняется нулями. Это, в частности, используется при заполнении таблиц - для форматирования и красоты;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char gender[6];
    float height, weight;

    printf("Enter your gender:\n");
    scanf("%s", gender);
    printf("Enter your height:\n");
    scanf("%f", &height);
    printf("Enter your weight:\n");
    scanf("%f", &weight);

    printf("%s\n", gender);
    printf("%10.3f\n", height);
    printf("%10.3f\n", weight);

    return 0;
}
```

Вообще, имеет смысл писать подробнее формат вывода, это добавляет определенности.

Comment: Я бы все же добавил между выводами или пробел, или перевод строки... Иначе все равно все будет выводиться одной кишкой...

Comment: @Harry подправил...

Comment: Но, по-моему, ТС просто не врубился, что в первых строках - это ввод данных, а не вывод :) И ничтоже сумняшеся решил, что `66.5
men174.50000066.500000` - это все **вывод** веса...

Comment: чтобы избежать [переполнение буфера в `scanf("%s", gender)`](https://ideone.com/Ox5ESM), можно использовать [`fgets(gender, sizeof gender, stdin)`](https://ideone.com/HfRX79)

Comment: @jfs можно и иногда нужно, но вопрос о другом был, а добавлять всякие сторонние детали не всегда нужно, а в данной ситуации и немного лень;)