# В Си посчитать количество малых/больших ascii букв, пропуск пробелов

Tags: c

Необходимо посчитать большие и малые буквы (с этим проблем нет), но столкнулся в Си с такой проблемой, что начинает происходить что-то странное, когда ввожу с клавиатуры пробел в строку. В шарпе с этим все в разы проще...

```
printf(" - Prosze podac slowo - \n");
scanf("%s",str);

for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(str[i]!=' '){
        if(str[i]<='z' && str[i]>='a')count++;
        else if(str[i]<='Z' && str[i]>='A')count2++;
        }
        else continue;
    }

printf("liczba wielkich liter: %d\n",count2);
printf("liczba malych liter: %d",count);
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf `%s`:

> Any number of non-whitespace characters, stopping at the first
>   whitespace character found. A terminating null character is
>   automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.
>   Любое количество непробельных символов...

Вы должны читать, пока не встретите перенос строки.
Либо использовать `gets`, но тут есть проблема с переполнением буфера при достаточно длинном вводе. Так что всё равно нужно проверять, был ли перенос или eof.

---

В Posix7 есть функция getline:

> ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n,
>          FILE *restrict stream);

Comment: А почему `fgets` нельзя использовать вместо уже выброшенного из стандарта `gets`? Или хотя бы `gets_s`? Чтоб о переполнении буфера забыть?

Answer (score 0):

[`scanf("%s",str)`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) читает до первого пробела только и вообще следует избегать так как [буфер может переполнить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738340/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85/738353#comment1126702_738353).

Чтобы посчитать количество ascii букв, достаточно по одному байту читать с помощью [`getchar()`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  // count chars
  uintmax_t count_lower = 0, count_upper = 0;
  for (int c; (c = getchar()) != EOF; ) {
    assert(c >= 0 && c <= UCHAR_MAX); // otherwise UB in ctype functions
    if (isupper(c)) // C locale
      ++count_upper;
    else if (islower(c))
      ++count_lower;
  }
  printf("upper: %ju, lower: %ju\n", count_upper, count_lower);
  return !feof(stdin); // success on eof
}
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/Rzoe1r):

```
$ cc *.c && ./a.out <<< 'abc ABCD'
upper: 4, lower: 3
```